# How can I persist a file uploaded to Play framework, using Scala?

Tags: forms, scala, file-upload, playframework, controller

I have a form for uploading a file which leads the following Controller Action method:

```
object FileUpload extends Controller
{
  def upload() = Action(parse.multipartFormData)
  {
    implicit request =>
    {
      val form = Form(tuple(
                            "description" -> text,
                            "image"       -> ignored(request.body.file("image")).verifying("File missing", _.isDefined)
                      ))

      form.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors => { Ok(views.html.files.uploadForm(formWithErrors)) },
        values         =>
        {
          request.body.file("image").map{ imageFile =>
            imageFile.ref.moveTo(new File("tmp/images"))
            Ok("Retrieved file %s" format imageFile.filename)
          }.getOrElse(BadRequest("File missing!"))
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

After making the "tmp/images" directory, when I submit a file through the form, I would get the expected Ok response.

However, when I look in that "tmp/images" directory, it remains empty.

So, where is the image going?  And, how can I save it?

Comment: Where did you create your 'tmp/images` directory...? Here "tmp/images" path is relative to your root project directory.

Comment: I created it in the root project directory.  Before I created it there, I would get errors saying the path does not exist, so it must be in the right place.

Comment: What you are missing is that the path provided is not a valid filepath. You need to provide a filename. `imageFile.ref.moveTo( new File( "tmp/images/" + imageFile.filename ) )` should do the trick.

Comment: It works!   If you offer this as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: No need for that. Happy to help. :)